# Extra sprite being displayed?

Tags: python, pygame

I have a problem with an extra sprite being displayed in my space invaders program that I am making for my A Level computing project.

It looks like this: [image: space invaders sprites]

My code looks like this:

```
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self,x,y,direction,enemy_type):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.EnemyType = enemy_type
        self.Direction = direction

        if enemy_type == 1:
            enemy_image = pygame.image.load("sprites\\enemy1_1.png")
            self.Speed = 1
            self.Score = 5

        if enemy_type == 2:
            enemy_image = pygame.image.load("sprites\\enemy1_1.png")
            self.Score = 15
            self.Speed = 1

        if enemy_type == 3:
            enemy_image = pygame.image.load("sprites\\enemy1_1.png")
            self.Score = 10
            self.Speed = 1

        if enemy_type == 4:
            enemy_image = pygame.image.load("sprites\\enemy1_1.png")
            self.Score = 20
            self.Speed = 1

        if enemy_type == 5:
            enemy_image = pygame.image.load("sprites\\enemy1_1.png")
            self.Score = 25
            self.Speed = 1

        self.image = pygame.Surface([100, 100])
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.image.blit(enemy_image,(0,0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

    def move_enemy(self):
        if self.Direction == "right":
            self.rect.x += self.Speed
        if self.Direction == "left":
            self.rect.x -= self.Speed

    #draw image
    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)


allEnemies = pygame.sprite.Group()
a_enemies = Enemy(50,50,"right",1)
allEnemies.add(a_enemies)


#For X coords
    spawnPositions = [100,200,300,400,500,600,700]

    yCoord = 10
#creating enemies
    for n in range(5):
        for i in range(len(spawnPositions)):
            xCoord = spawnPositions[i] 
            enemy_type = random.randint(1,5)
            enemy = Enemy(xCoord, yCoord,"right", enemy_type)
            allEnemies.add(enemy)
        yCoord = yCoord + 50
#update enemy positions
        loop = 0


        for enemy in (allEnemies.sprites()):
            if enemy.rect.x < 5:
                enemy.rect.y = enemy.rect.y + 15
                enemy.Direction = "right"
            if enemy.rect.x > 750:
                enemy.rect.y = enemy.rect.y + 15
                enemy.Direction = "left"
            loop =+1

        for enemy in (allEnemies.sprites()):
            enemy.move_enemy()
#draw enemies
        allEnemies.draw(gameDisplay)
```

I've cut out irrelevant bits of code from my program to help make it easier for you to understand. I'm not too sure why it does this but i'm trying to just make the enemy class just move within the rows like the picture shows, but an extra sprite appears next to them.

Comment: Why these lines? `a_enemies = Enemy(50,50,"right",1)
allEnemies.add(a_enemies)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra enemy is caused by the singel enemy that is add to the group when it is intiilaized:

> ```py
> a_enemies = Enemy(50,50,"right",1)
> allEnemies.add(a_enemies)
> ```

Remove that code, to solve the issue.